# Android: Button Click is not working

Tags: android

My application is Enter an amount, calculate the amount and display the amount.

I am using Android SDK 16. When i enter the amount and click on the calculate button i am getting the

SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length.

My Activity class is

```
   public class ChapterTwo extends Activity {

public static final String tag = "Chapter 2";

static{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new     
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}




@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chapter_two);

    final EditText mealpricefield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mealprice);
    final TextView answerfield = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);

            button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClickView(View v) {
            try {
                Log.i(tag, "onClick Invoked");
                // grab the meal price from UI
                String mealprice = mealpricefield.getText().toString();
                Log.i(tag, "meal price is [" + mealprice + "]");
                String answer = "";
                // check to see if meal price contains $
                if (mealprice.indexOf("$") == -1) {
                    mealprice = "$" + mealprice;
                }

                float fmp = 0.0F;
                // get currency formatter;
                NumberFormat nf = java.text.NumberFormat
                        .getCurrencyInstance();
                // grab the input meal price
                fmp = nf.parse(mealprice).floatValue();
                // let's give a nice tip
                fmp *= 1.2;
                Log.i(tag, " Total meal price Unformatted is [" + fmp + "]");
                // format our result
                answer = " Full Price, Including the 20% Tip is "
                        + nf.format(fmp);
                answerfield.setText(answer);
                Log.i(tag, " On Click Complete");

            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {

                Log.i(tag, "Parse Exception caught");
                answerfield.setText("Failed to Parse the Exception");
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(tag, "Failed To calculate the tip" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                answerfield.setText(e.getMessage());

            }

        }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}}
```

My Layout is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chapter 2 Android Tip Calculator"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mealprice"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" 
    android:inputType="text">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/calculate"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Calculate Tip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />
```

I am getting the following error in the log cat

```
10-23 20:19:26.232: E/Trace(699): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-23 20:19:27.092: D/gralloc_goldfish(699): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-23 20:19:33.262: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(699): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
10-23 20:24:22.106: I/Choreographer(699): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-23 20:27:52.824: I/Choreographer(699): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-23 20:31:13.323: E/SpannableStringBuilder(699): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-23 20:31:13.323: E/SpannableStringBuilder(699): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-23 20:31:32.552: I/Choreographer(699): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-23 20:39:44.723: I/Choreographer(699): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare all the views in main class and initialize them in onCreate() method:

```
public class ChapterTwo extends Activity {

public static final String tag = "Chapter 2";
EditText mealpricefield;
TextView answerfield;
Button button;
.
.
.
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chapter_two);

    mealpricefield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mealprice);
    answerfield = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
.
.
.
}
```

Also the code that you have placed in onClickView(View v) should be inside onClick(View v) that you have below in your code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: S: It worked, I kept all my code in the onClick(View V). It worked without any error. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Is there more code other than the one you posted?

Here are couple things I noticed:

1. Your code won't do anything when you press the button since you are not doing anything in the onClick(View v) method as pointed above. You have an onClickView(View v) function, which no one calls. You should move your code from onClickView() to onClick() and just get rid of the onClickView() method (or you can just call onClickView from onClick function).
2. If you move the code as noted above, your code will work, I even tested it myself just now to double check. (You are missing a </LinearLayout> tag in the copy-paste code above but I assume you had it).
3. The error log you posted shows an error from SpannableStringBuilder. But you are not using SpannableStringBuilder at all anywhere in your code, so either a) you have some other code or b) this error has nothing to do with your code.

What happens when you press the button? Does the application crash? What values are you using for testing when you see the issue? Is there any other log in the log that has your tag or application name? The log you posted doesn't show any force-close logs or any errors associated with your application.

On second thought, are you saying that your problem is that when you press the Calculate button, nothing happens? So you assumed you had an error and just thought that the error you saw in the log was the reason your code didn't work? If that's the case, all you have to do is just move the code block in onClickView() into onClick() and get rid of onClickView(). The error log is from some other program that has nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, this may be your problem.

Log.i(tag, " Total meal price Unformatted is [" + fmp + "]");

fmp is a float...  you are adding it to a string.

comment this line out and see if it works.